# Extract data from json in BigQuery

Tags: json, google-bigquery

I have a field, called **created_by** in a bigquery table, with text like this:

```
   created by      
  "{\"name\": \"Charles Darwin\", \"email\": \"theemail@domain.com\"}"
```

The field is a "STRING" type field.
What I need is to extract the name and the email in two sepparated field.
How can I achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

see below, link to google docs here:

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/json_functions#json_value

```
select json_value(json "{\"name\": \"Charles Darwin\", \"email\": \"theemail@domain.com\"}", '$.email') as getEmail
```

[getemail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c9wim.png)

```
select json_value(json "{\"name\": \"Charles Darwin\", \"email\": \"theemail@domain.com\"}", '$.name') as getName
```

[getName](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6SwXA.png)

Answer (score 0):

You may consider and try below approach using BigQuery's [REGEX_EXTRACT](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/string_functions#regexp_extract) function.

```sql
with sample_data as (
  select "{\"name\": \"Charles Darwin\", \"email\": \"theemail@domain.com\"}" as my_string
)

select REGEXP_EXTRACT(my_string, r'"name":(\D+),') as ext_name,
REGEXP_EXTRACT(my_string, r'"email":(.+)}') as ext_email
from sample_data
```

**Sample Output:**
[image]

My sample REGEX is the most basic one since I am not familiar with your complete data. You may enhance or create your own REGEX that can fit your needed validation based on your own analysis on your data.